# Show data using AJAX and PHP

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I try to code this and having a trouble says
Warning: Undefined array key "user_name" in E:\xampp\htdocs\tmpi\get_chat_interface.php on line 15

this is my php code`

```
try {
    $pdo = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=$dbname", $username, $password);
    $pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

    $recipientUsername = $_POST['user_name'];

    $stmt = $pdo->prepare("SELECT message FROM messages WHERE sender = ? OR receiver = ?");
    $stmt->execute([$recipientUsername, $recipientUsername]);

    echo "<div class='live-chat-name'><p>$recipientUsername</p></div>";
    echo "<div class='chat-content'>";

    while ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
        $message = $row['message'];
        echo "<p>$message</p>";
    }

    echo "</div>";
    echo "<div class='chat-input'>";
    echo "<form id='chatForm'>";
    echo "<input type='text' id='messageInput' placeholder='Send Message...' required>";
    echo "<input type='hidden' id='recipientUsername' value='$recipientUsername'>";
    echo "<button type='submit'>Send</button>";
    echo "</form>";
    echo "</div>";
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    echo "Error: " . $e->getMessage();
}
```

and here is the JS

```
function loadChatInterface(user_name) {
    // AJAX request to load the chat interface for a specific user
    $.ajax({
        url: 'get_chat_interface.php',
        method: 'POST',
        data: { user_name: user_name }, // Use the correct key here
        success: function (data) {
            $('#chatInterface').html(data);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Debug the array `$_POST`. Use `echo "<pre>";print_r($_POST);echo "</pre>";` before this line `$recipientUsername = $_POST['user_name'];`

Comment: this is the output, i dont know anything yet cause i am a newbie in programming
Array
(
)

Warning: Undefined array key "user_name" in E:\xampp\htdocs\tmpi\get_chat_interface.php on line 15

Comment: There is no call of "loadChatInterface" in your code

Comment: just like what @Adi said, echo the value of `$_POST` using the code provided so that we can see what the actual body you are trying to send in your request.

Comment: Do this: Comment **ALL** code from `$recipientUsername = $_POST['user_name'];` and below. then add `echo "<pre>";print_r($_POST);echo "</pre>";` so that you can see the request body.

Comment: The problem you have is that you try to retrieve the message in your PHP code regardless of whether the form has been submitted or not. You need to surround the first section with `if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "POST")` though I think that section should be in a separate file if you're calling it via Ajax.

Comment: Which version of jquery are you using ?